# How to JOIN two tables and get the following result?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Campaign Table data is currently like this

```
id    campaign_name
 1    florist
 2    dentist
 3    restaurants
 4    realestate
```

And my second table (lead)

```
id          campaign_id       business_id
 1               1                13456
 2               1                34563
 3               3                65987
 4               2                45654
 5               3                45632
```

I would like to list all the campaign name, total leads for that corresponding campaign by JOIN and GROUP BY.(codeigniter)

```
campaign_name                No. of leads
florist                            2
dentist                            1
restaurants                        2
realestate                         0
```

Comment: You'll want to use a left join, so you can can get 0 for the data that is in `Campaign` and has no corresponding records in leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your expected data using [active record/ query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) as

```
$this->db->select ( 'c.campaign_name,count(l.business_id) as no_of_leads' ,false)
        ->from ( 'campaign as c' )
        ->join ( 'leads l', 'c.id = l.campaign_id','left')
        ->group_by( 'c.campaign_name')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a left join

```
$this->db->select('campaign_name, COUNT(campaign_id) AS `No. of leads`');
$this->db->from('campaign');
$this->db->join('lead', 'campaign.id = lead.campaign_id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by( 'campaign.campaign_name' )
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Others posted the query builder code so here is the Raw SQL you will need

```
SELECT
   c.campaign_name,
   COUNT(l.id) as total_leads
FROM
   campaigns AS c
LEFT JOIN
   leads AS l ON c.id = l.campain_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Left Join is important because you'll want to count this:

```
 realestate                         0
```

Where you have a record in `campaigns` for ID 4, and no records in `leads` for that campaign id.  I would also count and group by the PKEYs,  you'll get better indexing and more reliability(because we know they are unique).